# Android service, alarmmanager, check online for updates, status bar notification

Tags: android, eclipse, service, alarmmanager

I have now spent 2 days trying to get this going. I am however completely bamboozled. Individually I have successfully got all the tasks working but I have NO idea how to go about the next part.

Please someone create the steps and simplify the tasks only. I don't need the code (trying to save you time). I need to know HOW this can be achieved.

1. Every 5/10/15/20/30/60 minutes (according to user preference in app), updates will be checked online receiving a number (number of updates since last check).
2. Even when the app is terminated, I am hoping this can run as a service so updates are still checked (if that's how it works)
3. Since looking into handler/timer/service/alarmmanager, I am really confused with this now so I also need to know the best way to achieve this.

So, could someone put it thus:

1. In 'name' activity, add the following code: ...
2. Create 'such' file, adding  etc etc in the manifest
3. In this part of the code, add your online check code
4. Put your status bar notify code here
   and so on...

I think the problem is I read way too much with peoples issues on SOF and got confused.

Truly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `Handler` for timing while application is running and `AlarmManager` otherwise. For simplicity you could use the latter for both tasks using this API:

```
public void setRepeating (int type, long triggerAtTime, long interval, PendingIntent operation)
```

I found an example in [this](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129) blog post. An excerpt:

1. Create a new `PendingIntent` with it's `getBroadcast()` method.
2. Create an alarm using method above of `AlarmManager`.
3. Create a `BroadcastReciever` and register it in `AndroidManifest.xml` as described in the [Developer Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html).
4. Check for updates in `onReceive` method of `BroadcastReceiver`.

Alternatively you could create an `Activity`:

1. First time it's started schedule an alarm but use `getActivity` method for intent instead and pass your activity class to it.
2. On subsequent runs check for updates.

Comment: Re: the link, I found that first but lost it amongst the 15 odd tabs I had open about this. Glad you found it again. I will try all the above (still looks confusing) and report back soon. Thanks for the reply